# What is wrong with my proof that, given two convergent sequences with $L\neq0$, that for all $n>max(N_1,N_2)$, $\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, solution-verification

The proof uses the fact that the limit of a convergent sequence is unique. I accidently found this when proving that the limit of the product of two convergent sequences is equal to the product of their limits.

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be convergent with limits $\neq 0$. Then, we have both

$n_a > N_a \Rightarrow |a_n - L_a| < \epsilon$ and $n_b > N_b \Rightarrow |b_n - L_b| < \epsilon$. Let $N = max(N_a, N_b)$.

Then, $n > N \Rightarrow |a_n - L_a||b_n - L_b| < \epsilon$. Expanding the product of the  two terms inside the absolute value signs, we obtain $a_n b_n -L_b a_n - L_a b_n +L_a L_b$. Keeping the $a_n b_n$ terms as they are, and factoring out a factor of $L_a L_b$ from the remaining terms, gives $a_n b_n -L_b L_a (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_n} - 1)$. However, from the uniqueness of a sequence's limit, and the fact that we can prove the (intended) theorem (that the limit of the product of two convergent sequences has limit $L_a L_b$ without contradicting the expansion I have derived so far, it follows that $L_b L_a (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_n} - 1) = L_b L_a \implies \frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_n} - 1 = 1) \implies \frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_n} = 2$.

From this, I would expect that $n > N \implies \frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_n} = 2$ for all such $n$. However, when I have tried this with the functions $\frac{n+2}{2n+1}$ and $\frac{3-8n}{n+2}$, using both Excel and my Casio fx-991ES PLUS for n = 10000000, I *almost* obtain a value of 2, but it ends up being equal to about 1.9999999125. Is this due to the computer being unable to work to the required accuracy, or have I missed some steps in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you've written.

First it does not always hold that
$$|a_n - L_a|\cdot|b_n - L_b| = a_nb_n - L_ba_n - L_ab_n + L_aL_b$$
for example take $a_n = 1, L_a = 2, b_n=2,L_b=1$. Then
\begin{align}
   |a_n - L_a|\cdot|b_n - L_b| &= |-1|\cdot|1| = 1 \\
   a_nb_n - L_ba_n - L_ab_n + L_aL_b &= (1)(2)-(1)(1)-(2)(2) + (2)(1) = -1
\end{align}
what you should have is
$$|a_n - L_a|\cdot|b_n - L_b| = |a_nb_n - L_ba_n - L_ab_n + L_aL_b|.$$

Second you have written that
$$L_bL_a\left (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} - 1 \right) = L_bL_a$$
when really you should have
$$
L_bL_a\left (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} - 1 \right) = a_nb_n.
$$
and taking limits on both sides you get
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L_bL_a\left (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} - 1 \right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_nb_n = L_aL_b.
$$

The thing about limits is that they don't say anything about equality for a fixed $n$, in particular there is no reason to expect that for any $n$ that
$$L_bL_a\left (\frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} - 1 \right) = L_aL_b.$$
For example,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
but for all finite $n$ we have $1/n \neq 0$.

Overall you really should approach this limit in the following way
\begin{align} 
   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{L_a} + \frac{b_n}{L_b} &= \frac{1}{L_a} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n + \frac{1}{L_b} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \\
&= \frac{1}{L_a}L_a + \frac{1}{L_b}L_b = 2,
\end{align}
but again there is no reason to expect an exact equality for any fixed $n$.